# SlickGrid make cell editable when tabing to it

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Ok, out the box slickGrid requires you to "double-click" to edit a cell(annoying)

I have gotten around that by modifying the main js file and adding

```
var cell = getCellFromEvent(e);
if (options.editable) {
    gotoCell(cell.row, cell.cell, true);
  }
```

to the bottom of:

```
function handleClick(e)
```

which is the function for single click

Anyone know how to edit on tab?

There is a function called `handleKeyDown()` but if I add that code snippet in there it wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `autoEdit` option to true.  See http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html for an example.